# Displaying SQLite specific data in a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm new in Python.
I had issues with Tkinter and Sqlite. I need to get a specific word in data base, given from input in the box "Find word".

```
#create function to search a record
def wordSearch():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydata.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM information WHERE my_word = ?")
```

records = c.fetchall()
    print(records)

```
#Loop thru results
print_records = ''
for record in records:
    print_records += str(record[0]) + " "+ str(record[1]) + " " + str(record[2])+'\n'

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


#create text boxes
wordSearch_entry = Entry(root, width = 30)
wordSearch_entry.grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5 )

#create text box labels

wordSearch_entry_label = Label(root, text = "Find word")
wordSearch_entry_label.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)


btn_wordSearch = Button(root, text="Search word", command=wordSearch)
btn_wordSearch.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 10, ipadx = 130)
```

Comment: You didn't supply argument to the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
con = sqlite3.connect('./mydata.db')
c = con.cursor()
def searchWord():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM information WHERE my_word = {} ".format(str(wordSearch_entry.get())) #Ok! We have found the words. Lets print it:
    for x in c: #'x' gonna append each result 'c' found.
        print(x)

searchWord()
```

Comment: It gives me an error sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: name     There is no conumn "name", but there is the row "name"

Comment: Try changing `{}` to `'{}'`.  But better use placeholder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def wordSearch():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydata.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c = c.execute("SELECT * FROM information WHERE my_word = ?",[wordSearch_entry.get()])
    records = c.fetchall()
    print(records)

    #Loop thru results
    print_records = ''
    for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[0]) + " "+ str(record[1]) + " " + str(record[2])+'\n'
        # wordSearch_entry_label['text']=print_records <--- if you want to show your results on wordSearch_entry_label.

#create text boxes
wordSearch_entry = Entry(root, width = 30)
wordSearch_entry.grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5 )

#create text box labels

wordSearch_entry_label = Label(root, text = "Find word")
wordSearch_entry_label.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)


btn_wordSearch = Button(root, text="Search word", command=wordSearch)
btn_wordSearch.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 10, ipadx = 130)
```

Hope It Helps!